# Defining an FK relationship in MVC using .EDMX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just ramping up on MVC 4 and have encountered an error in my application that I need some assistance in fixing.

I have an Author & Book table. The Author table is the parent, and you can have multiple Books associated with each author.

Everything is working well until I try to delete an Author that still has Books assigned to him. When that happens, I receive an error at SaveChanges() stating:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Book_Author".

The error makes perfect sense, but I would like the application to give a nice error message to the users rather than simply exploding.

How do I go about defining this relationship in the model so it doesn't cause the application to explode when you delete a record with children associated to it?

### Author Class

```
public partial class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        this.Book = new HashSet<Book>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

### Book Class

```
public partial class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

### Model

I have recently started attempting to override OnModelCreating, but it appears to have no affect.

```
public partial class BookEntities : DbContext
    {
        public BookEntities()
            : base("name=BookEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasRequired(p => p.Author)
                .WithMany(b => b.Books)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Books)
                .WithRequired(b => b.Author)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }
```

---

### Partial Updates

- This is an issue regarding 0..1-To-Many relationships
- I am using an .edmx. I've just learned that this negates the OnModelCreating method completely.
- It appears that I can throw a Linq statement into the DeleteConfirmed method to block this from crashing, but I really do not like that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

After spending a day struggling on this one issue, I decided to put some custom code into the DeleteConfirmed method to prevent the error from arising & to alert the user that this record could not be removed.
This is probably not the best way to handle the situation, but it is functional.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Author author = db.Authors.Find(id);

    // Count # of Books for this Author
    int count = (from book in db.Books
                        where book.BookId == id
                        select book.BookId).Count();

    // Prevent deletion of this record has any associated records
    if (count> 0)
    {
        TempData["errors"] = "Bad user! You can't delete this record yet!";
        return RedirectToAction("Delete");
    }
    else
    {
        db.Categories.Remove(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally do not use the attributes if I am also using the fluent API, so this code will be entirely convention and fluent API.

Your post does not specify, but the classic book=>authors model is a many to many relationship.  Your Entity code seems to be saying that there is exactly one author and exactly one book, while your fluent code seems to be implying that there are collections of Books and Authors.

FWIW, here is what I would Have:

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

and in the Override:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Books)
            .WithMany(b => b.Authors)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("AuthorBooks");
                    m.MapLeftKey("AuthorId");
                    m.MapRightKey("BookId");
                });
}
```

This will yield the db of:

[image]

I believe that is all you would need to get the cascade, by convention it should perform the cascade.

Please post if this is not what you were looking for.

Tal

Comment: I think it's close to what I need, but I'm really aiming for a 1-to-many relationship. I'm still plugging away at it.

Comment: Ok, if you are going one to many, then you need a **ICollection<Book>** in Author and both an **Author** and an **AuthorID** in the Book.   In the fluent then you need to only have  `modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Books)
                .WithRequired(b => b.Author);`

Comment: I've added a few notes in my original post. What I've recently discovered is that you the OnModelCreating method is never actually referenced if you're basing your model on an EMDX file. I'll need to find another approach to fixing this.